# Conversão de String para BigDecimal está dando erro e o método não salva

Tags: java, mysql, string, swing, mvc

Estou fazendo um sistema para videolocadora e na minha tela de categoria a um campo chamado valor para salvar o valor da minha categoria. Consegui fazer a conversão de String para BigDecimal utilizando os seguintes métodos: ToString, DecimalFormat, StringBigInteger, valueof, BigDecimal e ToPlainString mas a maioria da erro e não salva o valor da minha categoria!

Código:

```
private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(0);  

        if (!cmpValor.getText().equals("")) {  
            valor = new BigDecimal(cmpValor.getText());  
        }  

        categoriaController.salvar(cmpDescricao.getText(), valor);  

}
```

Obs: A minha tela categoria tem três JLabel: Código, descrição e valor e três JTextField que são respectivamente cmpCodigo, cmpDescriçao e cmpValor!

```
[code]Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at view.VideoCategoria.btnSalvarActionPerformed(VideoCategoria.java:205) 
at view.VideoCategoria.access$000(VideoCategoria.java:19) 
at view.VideoCategoria$1.actionPerformed(VideoCategoria.java:62) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) 
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252) 
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321) 
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292) 
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:489 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:227 
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75) 
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)[/co
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 205 da classe VideoCategoria?

Comment: Essa:  ' categoriaController.salvar(cmpDescricao.getText(), valor);  ' :)

Comment: Vc tem um problema de NullPointerException nessa linha, provavelmente o cmpDescricao está nulo nesse ponto, teste ele antes de pegar o `getText()`. Além disso, você está com alguma outra dificuldade?

Comment: Como testar ele?! Sou novato ainda em programação!

Comment: Acho que assim já resolve: `if(cmpDescricao !=null ) categoriaController.salvar(cmpDescricao.getText(), valor); ` Mas você tem que ver o pq dele estar chegando null ali, pode ser que tenha que rever a sua  logica

Comment: Testei mas continua dando erro na mesma linha : categoriaController.salvar(cmpDescricao.getText(), valor);

Comment: Então o que está nulo deve ser o `categoriaController`, confira se ele foi inicializado.

Comment: Eu já tinha inicializado ele : `private CategoriaController categoriaController; `

Comment: Isso é declarar, não inicializar. Você deve ter que atribuir um valor para ele de um objeto. Se você não estiver usando um framework geralmente se faz isso utilizando o `new`.

Comment: Deu certo aqui e valeu pela ajuda! Agora deu erro na CategoriaDAO vou tenta resolver aqui! Valeu!